# Measuring the impacts of renaming a TFS projects collection

Tags: tfs

To get rid of an issue with the name set previously for our projects collection, I have to rename it.

The procedure seems really simple :

- detach the collection
- rename the collection
- Reattach collection

My issue is that I do not have access right now to my preprod TFS and can't measure what will have to be changed/put back or what I need to communicate to my users.

So, there's my question : 
What are the impacts of changing a projects collection name except the URL changing ?

Thank you